# Heroku Facebook app index blank

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I'm trying to develop a Facebook app, I've already done this like ten times and it always worked like a charm. Thing is, my index page is showing up blank now, on the normal Heroku url and on Facebook. I've also tried the default index page for Heroku Facebook PHP and even that one is showing up blank.

Now, I've read that a lot of times this is because of secure surfing. But that can't be the problem here, since it doesn't even work on Heroku. This is the link: http://fathomless-thicket-9581.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `heroku logs` ? I had the same issue today with testing a new app. I used the example [here](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php) and followed the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook). The app worked on my local but not on heroku (nor facebook). After discovering the logs I found the following error:

```
[Thu Oct 24 06:29:13 2013] [error] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature.\n  thrown in /app/www/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1264
```

I set environment variables locally through vhost configuration and on heroku via config vars. It seems that although both config vars are set and correct (`heroku config`), when I echo them to the page (`echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].' / '.AppInfo::appID().' / '.AppInfo::appSecret();`) only one shows up on the heroku page (but both show up on my local, so that's why it's working there).

I removed both vars and reset them:

```
heroku config:unset FACEBOOK_SECRET
heroku config:unset FACEBOOK_APP_ID

heroku config:set FACEBOOK_SECRET=xxxxx...
heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=xxxxx...
```

now works for me

Comment: Hi Alyda, thanks for your answer, one question though, in which file do you change these settings?

Comment: you set these via the [command line](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). If your config vars are hard-coded in PHP, you shouldn't have this issue. Definitely run [heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) to get a better idea of why your page is blank.